# Объясните как под капотом работает метод start_polling у aiogram3 в связке с обычным запуском асинхронных задач через asyncio?

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Есть следующая функция запускаемая через asyncio.run(main())

```
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    task = asyncio.create_task(monitor_remind())#такой конструкцией создается подзадача
    await task # и мы ожидаем ее полного выполнения без нее если в коде встречается await asyncio.sleep(5) оставшийся код в этой функции не выполняется 
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
```

Но если мы запустим код, бот не запустится и будет работать только запущенная функция "monitor_remind()".
Код "monitor_remind()"

```
async def monitor_remind():
    while True:
        print("test")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

При запуске же такова кода все отлично работает:

```
   async def main():
        bot = Bot(token)
        dp = Dispatcher()
        asyncio.create_task(monitor_remind())
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
```

И при запуске этого кода в функции "monitor_remind()" при встрече await asyncio.sleep(5)
код продолжает работать.
Объясните пожалуйста как это под капотом работает и из-за чего так получается.

Comment: Вы же сами ответ написали. В одном случае вы ждёте окончания функции, в другом не джете

Comment: Не вы видимо с асинхронность не работали) Если запустить через первый способ, обычные функции то он доходит до await asyncio.sleep(5) и переключается на другие асинхронные функции пока эта спит, а потом возвращается к ее выполнению. Если запустить start_polling вот так же как и первую функцию task = asyncio.create_task(dp.start_polling(bot)) и на следующей строке await task то тоже будет работать.

Comment: Ну так то же самое - вы просто не ждёте окончания работы start_polling

Comment: Я не работал?))))  так при слееп оно переключается на уже запущенные тачки, а у вас таск со стартом полинга не запущен

Comment: @eri нет, по стеку ниже в нём можно найти ожидание завершения polling-тасков, внутри которых есть `while True:` (иначе бы работа бота сразу завершалась)

Comment: @eri Спасибо кажется понял, и сори что за это "Не вы видимо с асинхронность не работали)", не выключается он из-за метода вроде этого loop.run_forever()

Comment: @andreymal странно почему его тогда назвали старт

Comment: Тогда до await task оно и не доходит. Но оно то и не нужно. Такс же уже запущен

Answer (score 0):

```
await task # и мы ожидаем ее полного выполнения
```

бот не запустится до окончиания "ожидаем ее полного выполнения". не нужно ожидать тасков с вечными циклами - пусть живут сами по себе